# Мигание изображения в Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Решил сделать маленькую игрушку на Android, использую SurfaceView. Так вот, персонаж(пока-что это кубик 50х50) при движении мигает. Пробовал сделать много статичных изображений, нету мигания. Что с этим можно сделать?

Код самый простой:

```
private void draw(Canvas canvas){
   canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
   canvas.drawRect(currX,currY,currX+50,currY+50,paint);
}
```

Так-же пробовал советы с интернета:

```
private void draw(Canvas canvas){
   Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(windowWidth,windowHeight,
                                    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
   canvas1.setBitmap(bitmap);
   canvas1.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
   canvas1.drawRect(currX,currY,currX+50,currY+50,paint);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);
}
```

Comment: Для мигания, как минимум, нужно отрисовку "кубика" обернуть в`if` с условием когда рисовать, а когда нет.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

А чего тут разжёвывать... Добавьте себе переменную, обозначающую состояние объекта (виден/не виден), при отрисовке проверяйте её, а состояние изменяйте как душе угодно, например через раз:

```
boolean showObject = true;

private void draw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
    // проверяем
    if (showObject) {
        // рисуем
        canvas.drawRect(currX,currY,currX+50,currY+50,paint);
    }
    // изменяем состояние
    showObject = !showObject;
}
```